# .NET WebApi hits dispose before the action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have WebApi controller that manages users accounts. The controller has 3 methods: The constructor - gets parameter of type `UserManager<IdentityUser>` which is injected automaticly by ninject.
`Dispose` - disposing the UserManager. 
`Register` Action - registering new user.

I set breakpoints in `Register` action and `Dispose` method.

Note: The `Register` action called using ajax.

**NinjectWebCommon.cs**

```
kernel.Bind<UserManager<IdentityUser>>().ToConstant(Startup.UserManager);
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;


public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

[Route("api/Account/Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{ // **<---- Breakpoint**
        // code...
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{ // **<---- Breakpoint**
    if (disposing)
    {
        _userManager.Dispose();
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

After I press F5 (Start with debugging) the breakpoint inside `Dispose` method hits first. Then I filling the form and sending the request to `Register` action, the breakpoint inside it hits.

The problem is that the `UserManager` getting disposed before the action happens, How I can fix the code so the UserManager will dispose after the application stops?

Comment: Are you making a cross domain AJAX request?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov in "cross domain" - you mean from domain X.com to Y.com? if so then no, the request is from X.com to X.com/api/Account/Register.

Comment: Maybe your controller action is not called because of its name and you are simply getting 404? `Register` is not a standard name for a RESTful controller action. In ASP.NET Web API the standard approach is to have action names like HTTP verbs: Get, Post, Put, ... Are you sure that you have correct routing setup and that you are making a correct HTTP request?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I forgot to note that I set `RouteAttribute` on the `Register` action: `[Route("api/Account/Register")]`. The `Register` action processing but after the  `UserManager` object disposed in `Dispose` method that called first.called.

Comment: You ever get the feeling people are taking this ioc/injection/testing stuff a little too far?

Comment: @grennis I'm not taking the ioc/injection/testing stuff a too far. I just want to write tidy code, my way to do this is by using Test Driven Development.

Comment: How much collective time has been wasted on problems like this instead of solving the business problem at hand?

Comment: @grennis Zero, while this problem isn't solved I worked on another things. If you want to continue to discuss it you're welcome to send me a message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you disposing static object in controller (that disposing every request), at the next request, you are not going to be able to use the object on a second request.

Also, there is no need to dispose objects which was binded using `InSingletonScope` or `ToConstant` because they disposed automatically by `Ninject`.
If you want to create one instance for an object you should bind him using `InSingletonScope` or `ToConstant` (as described in [Ninject wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes)) then your object disposed when the kernel is disposed. Other way every time the binding will be injected, new instance of the object will be created.

Here is the fixed version of the code:

**NinjectWebCommon.cs**

```
kernel.Bind<UserManager<IdentityUser>>().ToConstant(Startup.UserManager); // Disposed when the kernel is disposed
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;


public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

[Route("api/Account/Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{
        // code...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Controllers are instantiated and disposed on every request.  If you pass in a singleton to the ctor and then dispose the singleton when the controller is disposed then you are not going to be able to use the singleton on a second request.

Why don't you just dispose Startup.UserManager on some global application shut down event?

Comment: That's what I did. I can't answer on mine question In 8 hours, when I will able, I will post what I did with examples and explanation.